# How to handle exception safety when calling untracked code

Tags: c#, interop, clr, pinvoke, swig

My C# application makes calls to functions from a .dll written in C++.
E.g., consider the following code snippet:

```
IntPtr request = RLibPINVOKE.new_Request();
HandleRef requestRef = new HandleRef(null, request);
IntPtr requestCreateKey = RLibPINVOKE.Request_CreateKey(requestRef, "some_URL", "some_Token");
HandleRef requestCreateKeyRef = new HandleRef(null, requestCreateKey);
RLibPINVOKE.delete_Request(requestRef);
```

As you can guess **RLibPINVOKE.new_Request()** function creates **Request** object dynamically (**new Request()**) in C++ side. So, in order to delete that object I called another function: **RLibPINVOKE.delete_Request(requestRef);**. Obviously, this is not exception safe code, hence we can easily have memory leak. I need to have RAII in C#, but I searched and found out that there is not such technique in C# as the language has garbage collector (at least it was my understanding). Also I noticed that RAII could be achieved via **using** directive, e.g.:

```
using(RAIIObject obj = new RAIIObject())
{
   // do some stuff
}
```

but it seems I can't apply this technique in my case. So how to resolve my issue properly?

```
// Suggested solution
    public class Wrapper : IDisposable
    {
        public Wrapper()
        {
            request = RLibPINVOKE.new_Request();
            requestRef = new HandleRef(null, request);
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            RLibPINVOKE.delete_Request(requestRef);
        }

        public HandleRef GetRef()
        {
            return requestRef;
        }

        private IntPtr request;
        private HandleRef requestRef;
    }
```

In the above solution I have to have **GetRef()** function as well, because I need to get **requestRef** object for further usage. Also, as I have other **new** functions as well (also their **delete** counterparts as well), e.g., RLibPINVOKE.new_decrypt(), RLibPINVOKE.delete_decrypt() etc., have to I  implement exactly that number of **Wrapper** classes? Is it reasonable way in general?

Comment: A common technique is to create a wrapper class implementing `IDisposable` and have `Dispose()` call `delete_Request`.

Comment: @KlausGütter please see changes as you suggested.

Comment: I don't know the full API, but if possible you should wrap all methods using the requestRef in this class so you don't have to expose it as public.

Comment: I can't wrap all methods using the requestRef, because other HandleRef objects use other objects as their second argument. Also I don't understand how to use this "Wrapper" class, because in my understanding new HandleRef(null, request) should be outside of this class and instead of *null* I should have something like this: new HandleRef(new Wrapper(), request). But, on the other hand, I should use "requestRef" object at least in the "Dispose" function.

Comment: Inherit from `SafeHandle`?